# Log cat shows Null Exception error

Tags: android, json, phpmyadmin, android-logcat

I am not able to understand the following log cat error. While verifying login details with php 
MySQL the log cat shows error. It is not able to verify whether the login password is matching or not

```
01-08 22:02:44.341: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 438K, 47% free 3581K/6663K, external 1849K/2137K, paused 86ms
01-08 22:02:44.853: I/System.out(336): Exception : null
01-08 22:02:45.481: W/InputManagerService(70): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40777108
```

The following is the java file for Android PHP Connection.

```
public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et,pass;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            login();                          
                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });
    }

    void login(){
        try{            

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://www.edu.jholhai.com/user_login.php"); // make sure the url is correct.

            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name",et.getText().toString().trim())); 

            // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pass.getText().toString().trim())); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // edited by James from coderzheaven.. from here....
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " +response); 
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " +response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this, UserPage.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();                
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
                builder.setTitle("Login Error.");
                builder.setMessage("User not Found.")  
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code. All we can say about this piece of log that somewhere in your code there's a `System.out.println("Exception : null")` or the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Response : " +response); 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("Response from PHP : " +response);
                dialog.dismiss(); // <=== NullPointerException
            }
        });
```

You are trying to dismiss the dialog which is created in showAlert() method but the method is called after the execution of

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Still the same problem exists.

Comment: Why are you dismissing the dialog even before displaying it ?

Comment: I changed the code now accordingly but its showing same error.

Comment: Can you change e.getMessage() to e.printStackTrace() and post the logcat ?

Comment: Cannot run the file after changing it to e.printStackTrace() since it shows no suggestion error.